# RuntimeError: _ARRAY_API is not PyCObject object & RuntimeError: _UFUNC_API is not PyCObject object

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cython, python-3.4, joblib

I have written such a code in python:

```
from selective_search import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
        img = skimage.io.imread('cat.jpg')
        regions = selective_search(img)
        for v, (i0, j0, i1, j1) in regions:
                regions = selective_search(img, \
                        color_spaces = ['rgb', 'hsv'], \
                        ks = [50, 150, 300], \
                        feature_masks = [0, 0, 1, 1])
```

When I run the code, I get these errors:

**RuntimeError: _ARRAY_API is not PyCObject object**
**RuntimeError: _UFUNC_API is not PyCObject object**

I'm importing selective_search, which you can see on this link: https://github.com/belltailjp/selective_search_py/blob/master/selective_search.py

I have installed all the dependencies below with required or later versions:

```
Cython==0.22
joblib==0.8.4
matplotlib==1.4.3
numpy==1.9.2
Pillow==2.8.1
PySide==1.2.2
PyYAML==3.11
scikit-image==0.11.3
scikit-learn==0.16.0
scipy==0.15.1
pytest==2.7.0
```

My default python version is 3.4.

How can I fix the problem?