# `RuntimeError: _ARRAY_API is not PyCapsule object` while using matplotlibcpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matplotlib, visual-c++, c++20

This question seemingly resembles [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339532/runtimeerror-array-api-is-not-pycobject-object-runtimeerror-ufunc-api-is-n), which has been left unanswered.

---

I am trying to setup `matplotplibcpp`, under `VC++20` in `VS2022`. After adding the addresses of `Python.h`, `matplotlibcpp.h`, and `arrayobject.h` to the linker setting of my project, the `MWE` below builds correctly.

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;
int main() {
    plt::plot({1,3,2,4});
    plt::show();
}
```

But when I compile it, I get the following error: `RuntimeError: _ARRAY_API is not PyCapsule object`.

Moreover, an exception is thrown at the following line

```
PyObject* matplotlib = PyImport_Import(matplotlibname);
```

as

[image]

If I check the box associated with the "Break when this exception type is thrown except when thrown from Python37.dll", and let the debugger continue, I get

[image]

Taking [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16040) into account, my linked python files are all `3.7`, and there is no clash between versions `2.-` and `3.-`.

So, how can one resolve this problem?

Comment: I misleaded myself. You run app that uses a 3rd party cpython module. I thought you run python with your cpython module. It seems there are troubles with numpy module versions.

Comment: @273K: My `numpy` version is `1.19.5`.